# Сделать правки в странице checkout wp+woo (сделать возможность правки количества штук в итоговом заказе)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

1. Сделать правки в странице checkout wp+woo(сделать возможность правки количества штук в итоговом заказе с выбором количества)

Сайт: https://trymmerok.fun/zamowienie/?add-to-cart=1084

2. Я использую редирект на чекаут чтобы пропустить шаг добавление в корзину, поэтому у меня появляется окно вверху страницы чекаут о возможности перейти в корзину. Подскажите как его скрыть.
   Скрины прикладываю.

Спасибо тем кто откликнется!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не фриланс биржа, если что, или приведите Ваши попытки решения данной проблемы и сообщество укажет Вам на Ваши ошибки или Вам не сюда.

Comment: я просто спросил может ктото сталкивался с этой проблемой и подскажет или решение или ссылку на подобный мануал.

Answer (score 0):

Окно можно скрыть стилями, woocomerce добавляет классы к body, просто скройте дочерний блок для этого класса.

Помещаем оба шорткода [woocommerce_cart] и [woocommerce_checkout] в контент страницы «Оформление заказа» и у вас вверху будет корзина со сменой количества.

Добавляем функцию что бы после оформления не висел блок с корзиной

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_cart_shortcode_content', 'site_cart_shortcode', 25 ); 
 
function site_cart_shortcode( $display_cart ) {
 
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        $display_cart = false;
    }
    return $display_cart;
 
}
```

И добавляем редирект когда корзина пуста

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'site_redirect_empty_cart', 25 );
 
function site_redirect_empty_cart() {
 
    if( 
      is_cart() 
      && is_checkout() 
      && 0 == WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() 
      && ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) 
      && ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) 
    ) {
 
        wp_safe_redirect( 'редиректим куда-то' );
        exit;
    }
}
```